# bigcommerce webdav workflow for theme development

Tags: themes, gruntjs, webdav, bigcommerce

I am currently working on a theme and am able to connect to the server via webdav.

Does anyone have experience syncing theme files with grunt using this plugin?https://github.com/avisi/grunt-webdav-sync

I tried following the URL construction and it comes back with this error "Resource requires authorization or authorization was denied"

Do you know how I should write the url to work with this grunt addon?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get this to work using grunt-rsync instead. I mounted the webdav template folder with Panic Transmit and then rsync my project folder that way. So far this is working great. I hope this helps.

Comment: could you share a code sample of your grunt task for reference?

Comment: @mjr Here is the grunt file that I used. It requires using Transmit FTP to mount a Webdav to your local machine. Then it rsyncs the changed files https://gist.github.com/JacobLett/644d0f9f232fbd2c87b8